# Use custom skin in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

I just finished creating an application in vb2010. It was successful with thanks to stackoverflow. But I will like to give the application a more appealing appearance by using custom skin. Please ho do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Mean By Theme Then Check this [Here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/T3-Visual-Basic-Theme-Archive.shtml)

Comment: Thanks, The Themes are beautiful, but Please how do I apply these themes in my project.... @Jadeja-RJ

Comment: Just Add New Class To your winforms application And Add full code to your class ,Now Just compile Your Progranm Once . .  Now you can see your theme components in ToolBox  Refer This Site http://tech.reboot.pro/showthread.php?tid=57